# To project CRS or not (Is Karney geodesic distance as good as projecting and then using Euclidean)

Tags: coordinate-system, geodesic

I'm used to using GeoPandas where I open a file which is usually in EPSG:4326 and then projecting it using `to_crs` so that when I do any area or distance related calculations, they won't be distorted (as much). When I'm done I `to_crs` back to EPSG:4326 and save a new file.

I'm looking to move over to doing geo work with rust and, in particular, the [geo](https://docs.rs/geo/latest/geo/) crate. It has functions like `EuclideanDistance` and `GeodesicDistance` which uses [Karney](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4448.pdf). **It seems to me that the former should be used on already projected coordinates whereas the latter should be used directly on EPSG:4326 (and others) thereby obviating the need for projection in my previous workflow.** Do I have that right? Is there any benefit to projecting and then using Euclidean instead of using the geodesic algorithm?